# T-SQL: foreign key that's not referencing a primary key

Tags: t-sql

I have the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE ContentNodes
(
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
   Revision INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   ParentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (Id, Revision)
)
```

How do I limit ParentId to only contain values from the Id column. Trying to make ParentId a foreign key gives me:

```
PRINT 'FK_ContentNodes_ParentId_ContentNodes';
ALTER TABLE ContentNodes
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ContentNodes_ParentId_ContentNodes FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES ContentNodes(Id);
GO
```

Error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'ContentNodes' that match the
>   referencing column list in the foreign
>   key
>   'FK_ContentNodes_ParentId_ContentNodes'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a compound primary key `(Id, Revision)` on your `ContentNodes`, you have to use **both columns** in a foreign key relation.

You **cannot** reference only parts of a primary key - simply cannot be done.

You have to either introduce a surrogate primary key into your table which is just a simple `INT IDENTITY` and then you can self-reference that single PK column, or you can (if it's possible in your data model) put a `UNIQUE INDEX` on that one column you want to reference:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UIX_ID 
  ON ContentNodes(Id)
```

Once you have a `UNIQUE INDEX` on that column, **then** you can use it as a FK reference.

Comment: Is there no way to contrain so that ParentId only can hold values that are in Id?